# Why When I scroll my ListView with CheckBox selected it becomes unselected?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I have seen some posts here talking about this but I did not see any answer accomplishing to my problem.

I have this ListView with some TextViews and one CheckBox, everything is OK except that when I scroll the list some checked become unchecked.

Here is my getView adapter code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Agendamento item = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_agendamento, parent, false);

        viewHolder.campoNomeCliente = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campoNomeCliente);
        viewHolder.campoNomePaciente = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nomePaciente);
        viewHolder.campoNomeMedico = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campoNomeMedico);
        viewHolder.campoCorStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campoCorStatus);
        viewHolder.campoCorStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campoCorStatus);
        viewHolder.campoDataHoraInc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.campoDataHoraInc);

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.marcado);

        viewHolder.chkMarcado = chk;
        viewHolder.chkMarcado.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String codigoMedico = item.getCodigoMedico();
    String codigoCliente = item.getCodigoCliente();

    Medico medico = rep.getMedicoPorCodigo(codigoMedico);
    Cliente cliente = rep.getClientePorCodigo(codigoCliente);

    String status = item.getStatus().trim();
    int backgroundColor = 0;
    if (status.equals("S")) {
        backgroundColor = R.color.corSeparada;
    }
    if (status.equals("F")) {
        backgroundColor = R.color.corFinalizada;
    }
    if (status.equals("E")) {
        backgroundColor = R.color.corEncerrada;
    }
    if (status.equals("N")) {
        backgroundColor = R.color.corNova;
    }

    String dataInc = item.getDataInclusao().replaceAll("[/]", "");
    String dataBr = "";
    if (!dataInc.trim().equals("")) {
        String dia = dataInc.substring(4, 6);
        String mes = dataInc.substring(6, 8);
        String ano = dataInc.substring(0, 4);
        dataBr = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
    }
    String horaInc = item.getHoraInclusao().trim();
    dataBr += " " + horaInc;

    viewHolder.campoCorStatus.setBackgroundResource(backgroundColor);
    viewHolder.campoNomeCliente.setText(cliente == null ? "(cliente)" : cliente.getNome());
    viewHolder.campoNomePaciente.setText(item.getNomePaciente());
    viewHolder.campoNomeMedico.setText(medico == null ? "(médico)" : medico.getNome());
    viewHolder.campoDataHoraInc.setText(dataBr + " (" + item.getId() + ")");

    final Agendamento item1 = item;
    viewHolder.chkMarcado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    viewHolder.chkMarcado.setChecked(item.isSelected());
    viewHolder.chkMarcado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                selectedList.add(item1);
            } else {
                selectedList.remove(item1);
            }
        }
    });

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cor_zebra2);
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cor_zebra1);
    }

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

Here is the result before scrolling up, after scrolling up those checked checkboxes become unchecked:

[image]

Comment: Because you're settings an OnCheckedChangedListener when it's created, and it's getting fired every time getView is called for that View since the ListView is reusing the Views you provide. If you want to avoid that, set the View's OnCheckChangedListener to null before setting it to checked or unchecked, then set the value, then set the OnCheckedChangeListener back to your listener. That needs to be done outside the if(convertView == null) check

Comment: ListView save instanses that currently are shown. When you scroll ListView you have the index of the first visible item and numbers of visible items. You must mannually implement select functionality using this information when user scroll listview

Comment: I just did what you said Guardanis but got the same result, please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `ListView` works is that it recycles the same views populated with different data. Hence, the need for the view holder pattern, which it looks like you are using.

So, in order for your list to work correctly, you need to save the checked state to your backing data model. It looks like you might already have a "selected" boolean in the model? If so, you just need to save the state to this boolean.

```
viewHolder.chkMarcado.setChecked(item.isSelected());
viewHolder.chkMarcado.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        item.setSelected(isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, works like a charm your suggestion!